# How to format Date using DateFormatter()

Tags: swift, date, nsdateformatter

I've been trying to format time using DateFormatter, but it keeps on returning nil. I know it's not in the proper format, which is why I've tried to format it on line 5. But the code keeps on printing error.

```
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"

        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "77000")
        if date != nil{
        print(dateFormatter.string(from: date!))
        }else{
            print("Error")
        }
```

Comment: What does the string `"77000"` represent?

Comment: And remember, when you want to convert a date/time string from one format to another, you need two date formats, not just one.

Comment: @maddy it's just seconds

Comment: @maddy why two?

Comment: Seconds from when? Hard to help when you don't put relevant details in your question.

Comment: You need two because the first converts the original string to a `Date` and the second converts the `Date` to the new string.

Comment: Also keep in mind that "77000" isn't a date. Apparently it's a number of seconds, presumably since midnight (you don't say what it really means). So using a DateFormatter isn't what you need. Just do some math. Convert the string to a number. Calculate hours and minutes from that number. Then format the hours and numbers into whatever format you want. All without using a DateFormatter.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble figuring out date formatters, it's helpful to use one to convert a `Date` object to a `String` (using the DateFormatter function `string(from:)`.) Log the results, study them, and use what you see to figure out how the date formatter differs from your desired date format.

In your case, you have a DateFormatter that uses a format of "hh:mm a". So it wants hours, a colon, minutes, and an AM/PM symbol, e.g. "12:23 PM".

Taking your code:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"

dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
print(dateString)
```

And running it in a playground, we get output like:

> 05:48 PM

You're trying to feed it a date string of "77000". You say that's "just seconds." But your date formatter doesn't expect seconds. It expects hours, minutes, and an AM/PM symbol.

### EDIT:

I guess there's no way to convert seconds to a date using a DateFormatter. There is, however, a format character, "A", which stands for milliseconds in a day. You can use that, but you'd need to multiply your seconds count by 1000.

If you want to input a date in **milliseconds** and convert it to hours, minutes, and an AM/PM symbol, you'll need 2 date formatters: one for the input format, and one for the output format. Your code might look like this:

```
let inputFormatter = DateFormatter()
inputFormatter.dateFormat = "A"

let outputFormatter = DateFormatter()
outputFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"

outputFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

let dateString = outputFormatter.string(from: Date())
print(dateString)

guard let dateFromSeconds = inputFormatter.date(from: "77000000") else {
    fatalError("Can't convert '77000000' to a date")
}

let displayString = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: dateFromSeconds, dateStyle: .medium, timeStyle: .medium)
print("displayString = \(displayString)")
```

### Edit #2:

However, if you want to add a number of seconds to today at midnight, I suggest a different approach. The Calendar class has a whole set of methods that let you do "Calendrical calculations". In this case we'll use `date(byAdding:value:to:wrappingComponents:)`.

That code might look like this (still using the outputFormatter from the code above) :

```
let calendar = Calendar.current

let midnight = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date()) //Get the date of midnight today, local time

if let newDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .second, value: 77000, to: midnight) {
    let output = outputFormatter.string(from: newDate)
    print("date using Calendar.date(byAdding:value:to:wrappingComponents) = \(output)")
}
```

That yields:

> date using Calendar.date(byAdding:value:to:wrappingComponents) = 09:23 PM

Comment: But there is no DateFormatter format that will convert 77000 seconds into a date. Your proposed solution doesn't work.

Comment: Sure there is. It will assume the current day. See my sample code. (I edited my answer.)

Comment: Oh rats, you're right. I did try the code, but misread the output. It looks like the only date formatter format that DOES work is  "milliseconds in day". I edited my answer to use that instead. Thanks for keeping me honest.

Comment: The better solution is to not use DateFormatter since there is no date involved here.

Comment: I wouldn't do that either. You'll probably end up with the wrong result in daylight saving transition days or days with leap seconds, etc. A value such as `"77000"` isn't a date. It's not really even a number of seconds since any specific midnight. Just do math on the number to calculate hours and minutes. Format those two numbers as desired. Getting Date, Calendar, or DateFormatter involved really isn't appropriate in a case like this. Especially with the complete lack of details on the question.

Comment: `extension Int {
    var hourAMPM: String {
        let hour = self/3600
        let amPM = hour < 12 ? "AM" : "PM"
        return .init(format: "%d:%02d", hour < 12 ? hour : hour-12, self / 60 % 60) + " " + amPM
    }}`